# How to configure Spring Batch Admin to use its JSON API

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using Spring Batch in my project with oracle and created 2-3 jobs, which is working fine and inserting into jobs meta data tables.

Now I would like to track jobs running information. I read about Spring Batch Admin JSON API. Do not want to use HTML UI. How we can use JSON API to get data from batch tables.

Comment: Share the code and full details of your Spring Batch

Comment: I do not have any query with my code. I am Using Spring batch to (Reader, processor, Writer) insert CSV data into database. Batch running information saves into Batch tables (Created by batch Spring batch itself) . Now to monitor, to get the job status and related information. I want to use  Spring Batch Admin - JSON API => http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/json.html. Need help in configuration with existing Spring Batch project. I think , now I am clear with my query.